# Why do I have to specify typeclass in function if it was declared in data definition?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

If I have an ADT with specified typeclass restrictions I still have to specify the same typeclass for each function using this data type. What the reason for this and how can I reduce unnecessary typing?

E.g.:

```
data Eq a => C a = V a
g :: C a -> Bool
g (V a) = a == a
```

I got:

```
test.hs:32:13:
    No instance for (Eq a)
      arising from a use of `=='
    In the expression: a == a
    In an equation for `g': g (V a) = a == a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

While:

```
g :: Eq a => C a -> Bool
```

Works fine, but if I have a long chain of functions it becomes a burden to specify a typeclass everytime:

```
f :: Eq a => C a -> Bool
f a = g a
```

Comment: One of the reasons why using data type contexts is discouraged is that it makes it impossible to define several useful instances (e.g.  `Functor`) for your data type. By only imposing the constraint on functions, your data type can be more flexible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the Haskell Report says so, basically. It's generally regarded as somewhat silly. Quoth [the GHC User Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt-style):

> All this behaviour contrasts with Haskell 98's peculiar treatment of contexts on a data type declaration (Section 4.2.1 of the Haskell 98 Report). In Haskell 98 the definition
>
> ```
> data Eq a => Set' a = MkSet' [a]
> ```
>
> gives MkSet' the same type as MkSet above. But instead of making available an (Eq a) constraint, pattern-matching on MkSet' requires an (Eq a) constraint! GHC faithfully implements this behaviour, odd though it is. But for GADT-style declarations, GHC's behaviour is much more useful, as well as much more intuitive.

Putting contexts on regular data definitions is discouraged and may (will?) be removed from the language at some point. Either put the context only on the function (which is what actually *needs* it, anyhow), or use GADT-style syntax to get the behavior you expected.

Comment: From [the release notes of GHC 7.2.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/release-7-2-1.html): _The `DatatypeContexts` extension (which will not be in the next Haskell language standard) is now off by default, and deprecated. It is still enabled by the `Haskell98` and `Haskell2010` languages._

Comment: @hammar: Aha, thanks! I knew it was being discussed but I hadn't realized it was moving along that quickly. Good riddance, it only served to confuse people.

Answer (score 6):

It's generally considered a bad idea to put a typeclass restriction on your ADT. Instead, leave it off and code normally using `(==)` wherever you have to. Your `Eq a` dependency will percolate up some of your functions and not others.